# How do create a stack screen with a class

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am coding an application that will have more than one page. I use '@react-navigation/native' and '@react-navigation/stack' to navigate between these pages. It works correctly when I write a function name in Stack.Screen's component. But I did not understand how the class call was made.

Api.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App(props) {
  // Load any resources or data that we need prior to rendering the app
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Homa Page" component={HomeScreen}/>
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

screens/HomeScreen.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { getSummary } from '../data/getSummary.js';

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ 
    isLoading: true,
  }
  this.getSummary = getSummary.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
  this.getSummary;
  }

  render(){
        return (
              <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
              <FlatList
                    data={ this.state.data}


            keyExtractor={(item) => item.CountryCode}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View> 
                    <Text>Country:{item.CountryCode}</Text>>
                    </View>
                )}
          />
          </View>
    );
  } 
}
```

Comment: Is that `<Stack.Screen name="Homa Page" component={<HomeScreen/>}/>`  could work?

Comment: Not working. ErrorMessage:`Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'Homa Page'. It must be a valid React Component.` I am using react navigation 5.

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Comment: No. I looked at react native and flutter for a project. Then I decided to go with flutter. @JosuéCarballoBaños